# How to Spawn Objects on Mouse Path? Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is what I want to achieve:

When moving the mouse (the mouse button is down) I want to save the whole mouse movement, I mean from the start (button click) point till the end (release button) point. And after releasing button I want to spawn some objects on the whole saved mouse path (like the picture), and the space between each two spawned objects should be the same.

- The world is in 3D, but the objects should spawn only on the X and Y axis, the Z axis will be fixe.

[image]

How can I do that in the code? I've already started it:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && !Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, transform.position.z);

        Vector3 curPosition = new Vector3(-Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint).x, -Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint).y, transform.position.z);

        if ((Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") != 0) || (Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") != 0));
        {
            GameObject TheBall = Instantiate(Ball, curPosition, Quaternion.identity);
            TheBall.transform.SetParent(transform, false);
        }         
    }
```

Comment: @Talk So my idea would be to save they position of your mouse into an array. When you finished dragging you could calculate the default distance between each point. So for example between 1 and 2, 2 and 3, 3 and 4 and so on. Then u would get an average distance and interpolate between them so you have positions where u spawn.

Comment: @AtLeastVision Can you please give me a code example? I don't know exactly how to do it

Comment: you can't just ask people to code the whole thing for you. Inside the Update() loop, read the mouse position and add it to a List<Vector2>. Then interpolate like he said. That's the quickest/dirtiest way.

Comment: You need to explain what is going wrong in the code you showed. You explained your problem well, but not what isn't working

Comment: @Roberto Ups. Am ye, I kinda wrote his code now but what ever. But you are completely right. Stackoverflow is not for coding someones else code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said you first may get the average space between each point. After that you would always create new point from the position of the one before. You could do this like that:

```cs
public GameObject prefab;
List<Vector2> points = new List<Vector2>();

void Update() {
    // You add the points in update to the List
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
        float totalDistance = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < points.Count-1; i++) {
            totalDistance += Vector2.Distance(points[i], points[i+1]);
        }
        float averageDistance = totalDistance / (points.Count-1);

        // Spawning first Point
        Vector2 lastPoint = points[0];
        Instantiate(
            prefab, 
            new Vector3(lastPoint.x, z, lastPoint.y), 
            Quaternion.identity
        );

        // Spawning other Points
        for(int i = 0; i < points.Count - 1; i++) {
            Vector2 spawnPos = lastPoint + ((points[i+1] - lastPoint).normalized * averageDistance)
            lastPoint = spawnPos; //Save the new point because you want create the next one from this one
            int z = 0; // The z you need
            Instantiate(
                prefab, 
                new Vector3(spawnPos.x, z, spawnPos.y), 
                Quaternion.identity
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Created the code for you. Your start code also had some issues but this here is working.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnCircles : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject prefab;
    public float Y;

    private Camera cam;
    private List<Vector2> points = new List<Vector2>();

    void Update() {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
            cam = Camera.main;
            Vector2 mousePos = new Vector2();
            mousePos.x = Input.mousePosition.x;
            mousePos.y = cam.pixelHeight - Input.mousePosition.y;
            Vector3 point = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, 10));
            points.Add(new Vector2(point.x, point.z * -1));
        }
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
            float totalDistance = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < points.Count - 1; i++) {
                totalDistance += Vector2.Distance(points[i], points[i + 1]);
            }
            float averageDistance = totalDistance / (points.Count - 1);

            // Spawning first Point
            Vector2 lastPoint = points[0];
            Instantiate(
                prefab,
                new Vector3(lastPoint.x, Y, lastPoint.y),
                Quaternion.identity
            );
            // Spawning other Points
            for(int i = 0; i < points.Count - 1; i++) {
                Vector2 spawnPos = lastPoint + ((points[i + 1] - lastPoint).normalized * averageDistance);

                lastPoint = spawnPos; //Save the new point because you want create the next one from this one
                Instantiate(
                    prefab,
                    new Vector3(spawnPos.x, Y, spawnPos.y),
                    Quaternion.identity
                );
            }
            // Resetting List
            points = new List<Vector2>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also consider accepting this answer if it helped you so nobody is making the afford to answer it again.

Comment: Thank you! but the code spawn the objects on the same Y position, I mean that I got an horizontal line of objects

Comment: @Taik The 2nd code? Do you use unity3d or unity2d? And even more important, in my example the x-rotation of my cam is -90 so it looks downwards. If you let it look straight you need to switch `Y` and `lastPoint.y` in the `new Vector3` I think.

Comment: Yes the 2nd code, and I use unity 3D, and yes my camera's X rotation is 0, it's straight.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208423/discussion-between-taik-and-at-least-vision).